# Why does using *ngIf = "authService.getUser()" in my top level app component html break my login component?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, authentication

I am new to Angular so please bear with my naivety. I created a login component, which I use to prevent access to router navigation links in the main app-component html until the user logs in. The login component itself is another routed page, and I wanted to instead add the login component to my mainpage, and hide the routing navigation links until the user logs in.

To hide the user navigation links in the app-component html I tried using 
*ngIf="authService.getUser()".

*ngIf="authService.getUser()" hides the navigation components until the user is logged in as expected, but it unexpectedly also didn't render the entirety of the login component (the user and password fields and submit button), except the first text which simply says "LOGIN". So the user has no way to login.
this is app.component.html:

```
  <app-login>

  </app-login>

<div class="page-header" >
   <div class="container">




      <div *ngIf="authService.getUser()" class="navLinks">
        <a  [routerLink]="['/home']"> Home</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/about']"> About App</a>


        <a [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/protected']">Protected</a>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

and these are my login component files

login.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  message: string;

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) {
    this.message = '';
  }

  login(username: string, password: string): boolean {
    this.message = '';
    if (!this.authService.login(username, password)) {
      this.message = 'Incorrect credentials.';
      setTimeout(function() {
        this.message = '';
      }.bind(this), 2500);
    }
    return false;
  }

  logout(): boolean {
    this.authService.logout();
    return false;
  }

}
```

login.component.html:

```
<h1>Login</h1>

<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="message">
  {{ message }}
</div>

<form class="form-inline" *ngIf="!authService.getUser()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">User: (type <em>user</em>)</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="username" #username>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password: (type <em>password</em>)</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" #password>
  </div>

  <a class="btn btn-default" (click)="login(username.value, password.value)">
    Submit
  </a>
</form>

<div class="well" *ngIf="authService.getUser()">
  Logged in as <b>{{ authService.getUser() }}</b>
  <a href (click)="logout()">Log out</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why are you using *ngIf="!authService.getUser()" inside your login component like this.

Semantically the purpose of this component is to be used when you're not logged.
So simply try to wrap your `<app-login></app-login>` in your app.component.html into a div wich have the *ngIf="!authService.getUser()"

Like this :

```
<div *ngIf="!authService.getUser()">
    <app-login></app-login>
</div>
```

Also I recommand you to not use directly the service method like this in the html but a flag instead for example isLogged init to false and update it when the user successfully logged.

Your ng-if will be : *ngIf="!isLogged **| async**"

Comment: My login component is both a way to log in and  way to log out. I want it to stay there so users can log out. Before they're logged in they should only be able to see and access the login page, but when they log in the component changes to its logged in form, and allows access to the previously hidden routes.

Answer (score 1):

What is in your `authService.getUser()` method? If it is asynchronous all you have to do is `*ngIf="(authService.getUser() | async)"`.